# Grouping by ID, Grouping by time (within 5 minutes of each activity), Find Time Difference of Activity in R

Tags: r, loops, time, dplyr

Is there a way for R to group by ID, and then to identify a 'break' in time and then calculate time difference?
For instance:

```
                ID               TIME              
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM               
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:13 AM
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:14 AM
```

Does anyone know of a way to find the time duration for A? Notice this is not a difftime problem. I performed a certain activity at 4:45:10 am, then again at 4:45:11 am. I then stopped this activity, and picked back up at 9:06pm. Is there code that can accurately group IDs, and then group time whilst detecting a huge gap in the time to avoid inaccurate values?

This is not the correct solution.

```
                       diff<- data %>%
                       mutate(diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(Endtime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
                       as.POSIXct(Starttime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), units = "secs"))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
 I will continue to research this. Thank you

Comment: Can you add the data sample with `dput` instead, so we've got the exact data types you're working with?

Comment: Hi Camille, I added the structure. Is this what you were looking for? Thank you.

Comment: That works, although you probably want the dates as an actual date-time object, not a factor, right? I'd imagine that should be your first step

Comment: What are you trying to do with the 2–5 minute window you mentioned? Only keep delta if it's under 5 minutes, or am I misreading that?

Comment: My apologies. I am just wanting to find accurate time differences within grouped data, being careful not to include 'long' time lags that will 'throw' the data off. This is why I mentioned the 5 minute time lag and to only include the delta if its 5 minutes or less. However, there may be a better way to do this. I am just not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned above, the first thing to do is convert your date-times to a date-time object; I'm using `lubridate` for this. Since you want to keep delta within some threshold, I saved a threshold duration of 5 minutes which you can change as needed. If differences are more than that, make them `NA`.

I'm doing the diffing in 2 steps, just so you can see the original difference vs the one with long differences removed. You'll probably want to just do that in one step.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

thresh <- duration(5, units = "minutes")

sample_df %>%
  mutate(TIME = mdy_hms(TIME)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(diff1 = TIME - lag(TIME)) %>%
  mutate(delta = if_else(diff1 < thresh, diff1, NA_real_))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>    ID    TIME                diff1      delta  
#>    <chr> <dttm>              <drtn>     <drtn> 
#>  1 A     2019-12-18 04:45:10    NA secs NA secs
#>  2 A     2019-12-18 04:45:11     1 secs  1 secs
#>  3 A     2019-12-18 16:06:59 40908 secs NA secs
#>  4 A     2019-12-18 16:07:01     2 secs  2 secs
#>  5 B     2019-12-18 04:14:13    NA secs NA secs
#>  6 B     2019-12-18 04:14:14     1 secs  1 secs
#>  7 B     2019-12-18 04:14:15     1 secs  1 secs
#>  8 C     2019-12-18 04:59:49    NA secs NA secs
#>  9 C     2019-12-18 04:59:50     1 secs  1 secs
#> 10 C     2019-12-18 04:59:51     1 secs  1 secs
```

Using `dplyr::if_else` rather than the base `ifelse` was handy because it uses strict typing, which helped make sure I kept the delta column as a duration object, rather than losing its time component and just getting a numeric, which would be the case with `NA` instead of `NA_real_`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I am not explaining the problem too clearly or maybe a loop needs to be created. I will re-word this. The solution you provided is very helpful but its still not solving my particular problem. On row 3, it says the time diff is 40,908 seconds, however, is there a way to separate that calculation and have it start from row 3 and row 4, calculating times 16:06:59 and 16:07:01 versus calculating 4:45:11 and 16:06:59? The IDs are grouped correctly, but my calculations are off because it keeps calculating the wrong times

Comment: So you want to mark off pairs within each group, and take the difference between those? In that case, what would you do with cases like group B where there are 3 observations?

Comment: Hi Camiile, not necessarily pairs. The goal is to calculate the duration of similar group IDS within similar time spans. So, group B would be a total duration of the 3 activities.  For instance, I performed a specific activity, A at 4:45:10, and then again at 4:45:11 so this is 1 sec. Then I paused, and picked up this same activity at 16:06:59 to 16:07:01 so these are my durations for Group A. Then for Group B, I started the activity at 4:14:13 and 4:14:14 and then at 4:14:15. For Group C, I started an activity at 4:59:50 and 4:59:51.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
library(lubridate)
sample_df$TIME = mdy_hms(sample_df$TIME)

sample_df = sample_df %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            # lag basically bring the next value one step up
            # so we can subtract value at index 0 and index 1, index 1 and index 2 and so on....
            mutate(time_diff = TIME - lag(TIME, n = 1, default = NA)) %>% 
            mutate(time_diff = replace_na(time_diff, 0))
```

Hope this gives you some idea.
For understanding, do it in two steps:

```
sample_df = sample_df %>%
            group_by(ID) %>%
            mutate(time_lag = dplyr::lag(TIME, n = 1, default = NA)) %>% 
            mutate(time_diff = TIME - time_lag) %>% 
            mutate(time_diff = replace_na(time_diff, 0))
```

Check how `time_lag` column looks.

Comment: I think this works! Can you please explain exactly what it is doing? I am still learning. I just want to fully evaluate and understand it, so that I can improve.

Comment: Ok thank you. The command still isn't solving the problem as I Iooked more closely. I am still getting this:  ID 'A'  12/18/2019 2:43:02 AM     time diff 1
ID 'A' 12/18/2019 4:14:06 AM     time diff 5464        Maybe I am not wording it correctly, but the time difference of 5464 secs is not correct. The time stopped at 2:43, and picked back up at 4:14

Comment: Check why is it 5464, what the next date is using for subtraction, can you show both the time stamps. The calculation looks fine to me on the given sample.